# Spring Hibernate without creating tables

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I created a database and generated some entities from it. Now I want to plug in with Spring framework. The problem is that when I deploy to Wildfly, it attempts to create the tables in my database, and fails because the tables are there.

My context.xml file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!--
           DATABASE SETUP 
    -->

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="username" value="****" />
        <property name="password" value="****" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.1.1.1:1521:XE" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="examplePU" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDao" class="com.foobar.dao.user.JpaUserDao">
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!--
           INIT REST COMPONENTS 
    -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.foobar.rest.resources" />

    <bean id="objectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" />

    <!-- 
            SPRING SECURITY SETUP
    -->

    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="com.foobar.security.SaltedSHA256PasswordEncoder">
        <constructor-arg value="secret" />
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDao">
            <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"></security:password-encoder>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:http
        realm="Protected API"
        use-expressions="true"
        auto-config="false"
        create-session="stateless"
        entry-point-ref="unauthorizedEntryPoint"
        authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/user/authenticate" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url method="GET" pattern="/rest/news/**" access="hasRole('user')" />
        <security:intercept-url method="PUT" pattern="/rest/news/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />
        <security:intercept-url method="POST" pattern="/rest/news/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />
        <security:intercept-url method="DELETE" pattern="/rest/news/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />
    </security:http>

    <bean id="unauthorizedEntryPoint" class="com.foobar.rest.UnauthorizedEntryPoint" />

    <bean class="com.foobar.rest.AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter" id="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="userDao" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

This is the log from wildfly

```
2014-04-02 22:31:54,170 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 41) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "portal-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"portal-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#OneW2\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"portal-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#OneW2\": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to execute JPA schema generation create command [***]
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to execute JPA schema generation create command [***]
    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table \"XXX\" already exists; SQL statement:
*** [42101-173]"}}
2014-04-02 22:31:54,172 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 41) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "portal-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"portal-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#OneW2\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"portal-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#OneW2\": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to execute JPA schema generation create command [***]
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to execute JPA schema generation create command [***]
    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table \"XXX\" already exists; SQL statement:
*** [42101-173]"}}
2014-04-02 22:31:54,174 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010418: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = portal-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war_org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver_2_2
2014-04-02 22:31:54,173 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'portal-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#examplePU'
2014-04-02 22:31:54,177 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'portal-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#examplePU'
2014-04-02 22:31:54,177 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'portal-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#OneW2'
2014-04-02 22:31:54,336 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment portal-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war (runtime-name: portal-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war) in 163ms
2014-04-02 22:31:54,337 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 41) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."portal-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."portal-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."portal-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."portal-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."portal-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".ee.ComponentRegistry (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/portal-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."portal-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#OneW2"
```

How can I disable table recreation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem *could be* in your hibernate configuration file.

`Please look into a property hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`

It can be one of these values and explanation for each one of them.

```
validate: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
update: update the schema.
create: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
create-drop: drop the schema at the end of the session.
```

So according to your needs, set the property in the file

Answer (score 2):

Try by putting below line inside jpaProperties property

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
```

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use Hibernate's hbm2ddl feature.

Then you should use the validate value:

```
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate">
```

See [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-misc-properties) about this feature.

Comment: Is this on the `persistence.xml` file?

Comment: Yes it is usually there.

Answer (score 1):

Add following in JPA properties

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
```

This will alter table in case of change in table structure,
will create new table in in case table is not present,
will insert in to table in case table is present.